# Use screen space on Tablet

Tags: feature-request, android-app

When using the Andriod App on a tablet, there is plenty screen space available.
When answering a question, the answer input form is fullscreen and you cannot see the question you are answering to, which is quite helpful often.
It would be nice to see the question that I'm currently answering when answering with the Android App from a tablet.